# How to bring a Windows application back onscreen?

Tags: windows, display

After many re-configurations of screens I commonly find some applications have saved their position off screen someplace.

What is a good way to force them back onscreen so I can re-position them again?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the built-in move function in Windows. The [How-To Geek](https://superuser.com/users/4102/the-how-to-geek) has an [article on it](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/).

Summary:

- Right click the application in taskbar
- Select "Move"
- Press any one of the arrow keys on the keyboard
- Click somewhere on your screen

Comment: I always alt-tabbed and then alt-spaced, but this is the answer I would have given too.

Comment: Move doesn't necessarily appear on the context menu of all application.

Comment: this did the trick (after I undid maximize)  Thanks!

Comment: It should appear in the system menu of any application that can be moved by standard means.

Comment: it is important to note that some 'edgecases' exist (pardon the pun) where you may have to disable 'activeation follows mouse' in tweakui so that the keyboard focus remains on the 'move' rather than where the cross-hairs are.

Answer (score 8):

In case you want to reposition many windows, just right click on the taskbar and tile them.

Comment: Or cascade of course

Comment: of course    :)

Comment: A last-ditch method: Kill the app. Then find the app's entries in the registry - should be under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\<companyName>\ ...  - and look for registry values where the app has saved its window position. There will usually be four values with names that include variations of x_pos, y_pos, x_size, and y_size. Change the first two to each be 100. If the developer was Bad you may find this under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\... instead, or if the app is ancient, in an .INI file associated with the app.