# How can I move a window that cannot be moved by mouse?

Tags: windows-7, notepad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bring a windows application back onscreen?](https://superuser.com/questions/35095/how-to-bring-a-windows-application-back-onscreen)

I have downloaded a version of Finale Notepad on Windows 7. When I first used it it functioned perfectly.

Every time I opened it a popup asking me about downloading a different version would show up that I could just click out of. When the pop up appeared I was unable to quit out of the window or move it at all, but it posed no issue.

Apparently, though, the last time I quit out of the program, the screen must have been dragged down below my taskbar. Now, I am unable to quit out of the popup when I reopen the program, meaning I can't access it at all.

I tried restarting my computer, uninstalling the program, downloading different versions of the program, and even using alternate methods of moving it, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but nothing works.

Comment: What about in the taskbar? Most popups will stack a new icon below the main one. If you roll over that and click on the preview you should be able to right click and select move and use your arrow keys to bring it up.

Comment: Or right click the task bar and tell it to auto-hide and then see if you can grab the window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the window focus first.

If it appears in the taskbar then just click on its name. Here you can invoke the context menu by right-clicking and selecting the Move item. Do NOT touch the mouse at this time. Use one of the cursor keys on your keyboard. Once you do that, *then* you can use the mouse IIRC.

If not in the taskbar, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until nothing you see is in focus. The shortcut for move is usually <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and use one of the arrow keys start moving your window. If <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> does not work, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to see its context menu and then select move or click <kbd>M</kbd>.

EDIT:

For completeness, a trick that works (tested with Windows 7) is to change the resolution of the desktop. Windows then rearranges windows to be visible.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, but I'll try... Thank you, you incredible wizard.